# Load library in library codeigneter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why i get this error?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Lib_curl::$lib_parent
>
> Filename: libraries/lib_curl.php
>
> Line Number: 14

this is my controller

```
public function shoppingcart()
    {
        $this->load->library(array('curl', 'lib_curl', 'lib_parent'));

        if($this->input->post('addtocart', TRUE))
        {
            $type = $this->input->post('type', TRUE);
            $id = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
            $Weight = $this->input->post('Weight', TRUE);
            $ASIN = $this->input->post('ASIN', TRUE);
            $qty = $this->input->post('qty', TRUE);

            if($this->lib_curl->cek_shipping_indous($type,$id,$this->config->item('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),$this->config->item('AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG'),$this->config->item('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')))
            {
                //indonesia
            }
            else
            {
                //US
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my library

```
public function cek_shipping_indous($tipe,$items,$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,$AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    {
        $params = array(
                'Service' => 'AWSECommerceService',
                'AWSAccessKeyId' => $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                'AssociateTag' => $AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
                'Timestamp' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
                'Operation' => 'CartCreate',
                "Item.1.".$tipe."" => $items,
                'Item.1.Quantity' => '1',
            );
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->lib_parent->amazon_get_data($params,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY));
        $this->lib_parent->echo_array($xml);
    }
```

where the wrong in my code?

thank you

Comment: try to require the lib_parent library in your lib_curl library

Comment: use the `get_instance()` function to access codeigniter's native resources within your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy you need to create an instance

```
Class mylib
{
    public $CI;

    function index()
    {
        $this->CI   =   &get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('another_library');

        $this->another_library->method();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In code you use library function so you need to create as below

```
var $CI;

function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
}
```

this code you need to add under the class it will be usefull and now you can load model use their functions as well.